# Apache rewrite relative URL to application

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, mod-proxy

I have web application running on localhost and listening on port 5050.
I would like to have this web application under URL with relative path domain.tld/page/app

I tried to use mod_rewrite:

```
    <Location /page/app>
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteRule .*$ http://127.0.0.1:5050/$1 [P,QSA,NE]
    </Location>
```

This rewrites domain.tld/page/app to domain.tld/login which is not a valid URL on my server.

Is it possible to reverse the rewrite?
I can't use ProxyPassReverse because I need to remove relative path from URL when I proxy the request to the application.

Comment: Where is `/login` coming from? This would seem to be the result of your web application logic, as it doesn't appear to have anything to do with these directives?

Comment: @MrWhite Yes it is coming from application logic. Application was not written to use relative path. I didn't write this app and I don't want to recompile it.

Answer (score 0):

This is a textbook case with [mod_proxy](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html).

```
ProxyPass         "/page/app/" "http://127.0.0.1:5050/"
ProxyPassReverse  "/page/app/" "http://127.0.0.1:5050/"
```

Notice that with this syntax you don't use this inside a `<Location>`.

Comment: This changes the URL in browser to domain.tld/login and I get 404 error. The URL should be domain.tld/page/app/login